# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification coming with empty data

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using the FCM Legacy HTTP API to send notifications to my React-Native Apps.  When I send notifications with the "data" block filled out, I see all the data on my app.  When I just populate the "notification" block however the message is empty when I receive it.

Is it possible to send true notifications through the API?  Or can it only be used for data messages?  I've been scouring through the documentation for a day now and Firebase seems to indicate it would send a real notification, some blog posts say only data goes out.  In any case, I receive the message on the app in a call back when the app is open, but the title and text are missing.  When the app is closed I don't get any notification sent to the system notification bar.
I'm basing the structure on the firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Here is my code on the sending side (PHP):

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$data = array(
    "to"=>"/topics/myapp.notification",
    "notification" => array(
          "title"=>$title,
          "body"=>$body
    )
);

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                 "Authorization: key=" . $appInfo["server_key"] . "\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data)
   )
  );


$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

On the app side, I'm listening for the message when the app is open using:

```
this.messagePushListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
});
```

The message I receive is missing the title and the message:

```
{"_collapseKey":"com.xxx.myapp","_data":{},"_from":"/topics/myapp.notification","_messageId":"-M6IZKep_yvL4rxxxxx","_ttl":3600}
```

Comment: did you set the data alongside with  `.setTitle(notification.title)`    `.setBody(notification.body)`    so the final result will be:   `.setTitle(notification.title)`  `.setBody(notification.body)`  `.setData(notification.data)` when you create a listener at `this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification`?

Comment: @JohnP did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue here.